# How to print image with HOIN H58 printer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I tested all code available on internet but no solution found. printer prints random numbers when i print image as Data form.

This is User Manual of printer: [User Manual of HOIN thermal printer](http://www.xmjjdz.com/downloads/manual/en/POS-58%20User's%20Manual.pdf)

Here is IOS SDK (for ble) for HOIN printer: [HOIN SDK](http://hoinprinter.com/en/download)

```
let ble = BLElib()
ble.connect(peripheral)
let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)
ble.send(data)
```

and Here is my dummy project: [Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovrrymq5xldq8cn/Demo%20BLE%20Printer.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Can it really print an image sent like this? Could you try to: do print("dataSend: \(dataSend as NSData)` and check if it prints something similar? Or even use a small image (better), give it to us?

Comment: Nothing in the manual indicates that you an send a PNG to the printer and have it print it.

Comment: In manual please read "Bit Image Command" section and i think this is the way to print bit map image but i don't know how to use this print command.

Comment: iOS SDK is not 64 bit compatible so not working